Transistor constant current LED photocoupler
I have this shown circuit below and I'd like to have 5 mA constant current on the LED (Vf = 1.2 - 1.4 V), Vcc = 5 V, NPN 2N2222. Some circuit use the Zener diode and other use just a regular diode. What would be the right resistor values and and if is better to place the Zener diode or exclude it.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

What accuracy do you need for the 5 mA?

Unless you have a very good reason to use an active constant current circuit a simple series 750 ohm resistor will be better in some ways.
The current will be a bit different from unit-to-unit, but only a few percent due to the LED variations. There are also variations due to resistor tolerances and Vdd tolerance.
Compared to the standard 2-transistor current sink/source, the current will be better defined (Vbe variations from transistor to transistor) and more stable with temperature (the 5mA at room temperature with the transistor circuit will be more like 6mA at -40'C and 4mA at 80'C - about +/-20%). Versus less than +/-1% variation for the resistor circuit. Not to mention simpler and thus less expensive and more reliable.
Where it definitely does come in handy is when Vdd can vary over a wide range (as with a general-purpose SSR input circuit w here the user can apply 3V or 30V) or when the LED voltage is fairly close to Vdd so small Vf variations result in large changes in current with a simple resistor.
Optocouplers are fairly crude devices anyhow, and the main thing is to have enough LED current but not so much as to prematurely age the LED so your circuit fails after less time than the expected product lifetime. It's not unusual to specify 50-100% safety margin to account for normal aging.
BTW, for back of the envelope calculations, the Vf variation with temperature is about -2mV/K for either an IR LED or a transistor Vbe, however the sensitivity of LED current to Vf is related to that coefficient divided by the remaining voltage across a series resistors for the simple series resistor circuit. That's about 3.8V for a 1.2V IR LED as used in optocouplers and a 5V supply, so the coefficient is roughly +530ppm/K. For the transistor Vbe it's 2mV out of 600mV so about -3300ppm/K or about 6x worse. Using some common simplifications such as 1/(1+a)~= -a for a << 1.

This is sound advice. The exact current is not as important as it being not too small and not too big. A simple resistor will do the job just fine, and it doesn't change the reaction time of the LED. Presumably an optocoupler is used to pass some on/off signal, and it helps to have the speed limited by the optocoupler itself, not by a complicated driver circuit that may be slow. It doesn't have to be slow just because it's complex, but it's all too easy to make something slow without realizing it.

A regular diode won't work as shown. A 3.3 V zener could work, but low voltage zeners have soft knees, so you need to allow for that. It will be sensitive to Vcc changes.
This circuit will work better for a Vcc of 5V. These values will give you an LED current of about 4.8 mA. The accuracy is dependent on the transistor Vbe drops, which will vary over temperature.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

I noticed circuits with just a diode for negative protection, but in my case I like to place an input between 5 to 10v, so zener diode make sense as long giving the zener enough current to breakdown and thus ic current won't change much when the input  volatge increases. I also tried, without using a zenre diode just a resitor like 10k

A regular diode would not work here, since you need significantly greater than 0.7V at Q1's base. The direction of D1 (reverse biased) implies that it's supposed to be a zener diode, but the symbol is incorrect.
Using a 3.3V zener diode for D1, in the orientation shown, you can expect 3.3V at the base, and about 0.7V lower at Q1's emitter, which is 2.6V. To have 5mA through R2:
$$ R_2 = \frac{2.6V}{5mA} \approx 500\Omega $$
Since collector current is roughly 5mA, worst case base current for a 2N2222 might be 50 times smaller:
$$ I_B \approx \frac{5mA}{50} \approx 100\mu A $$
D1 needs current to shunt, so current through R1 should be more, say double that. Voltage across R1 is \$V_{R1} = 5V - 3.3V = 1.7V\$, so:
$$ R_1 = \frac{1.7V}{200\mu A} = 8.5k\Omega $$
It seems to me that everything looks right. Resistor R1 isn't critical, 8.2kΩ will work fine. R2 is responsible for setting LED current, so you should stay within 10% or so of the calculated 500Ω.

The resistor value is easily determined by  figuring out the voltage across it.
That voltage is determined by the voltage on the base pin of the transistor, minus the base-emitter voltage drop (Vbe), which is typically assumed to be about 0.6-0.7V.
Let's assume you are using a 3.6V zener diode.
3.6V - 0.6V = 3V
Now we calculate the needed value of the resistor, using 3V across it, and about 5mA through it:
R = 3 V / 0.005 A = 600 Ω
In reality, the 3.6V zener will give you a significantly lower voltage if you don't reduce the R1 resistor value to allow for about 5-20 mA current through it. That would defeat the purpose of using a constant current source for the current that is equal to or less than the bias current.
You could use two ordinary forward-biased diodes instead, which will give you more stable resulting voltage of around 0.6 V across the resistor, while leaving the high value resistor R1 in place.
When you have a stable, regulated voltage applied across a device whose voltage at its given current is also fairly stable, the best "current source" would be just a simple resistor.
In this case, you have presumably regulated 5V and the opto-coupler LED uses about 1.3V, so you simply calculate a resistor value for 5 - 1.3 = 3.7 volts and 5 mA, which is about 740 Ω, and the closest standard value is 750 Ω.

A transistor's V(BE) is less temperature-sensitive than a LED's Vf. Thus, we can use a current mirror to slightly improve the stability of the LED current. We take the stable 5V as a reference, and use a resistor to convert this voltage, minus 1 V(BE) drop, into a current, that then drives the LED.
This circuit consumes twice the power than the simplest, and most likely sufficient, resistor+LED circuit. But it does do a somewhat better job at current regulation than just a resistor+LED. I'm showing it just because I can, not because there's much use for such a circuit in your application. This circuit is more useful with lower supply voltages, say 2V..3V, where changes in LED's Vf play a much bigger role.
In the circuit below, V1 and V2 model thermal changes in V(BE). In a physical circuit, they are internal to the transistors.
Over a temperature range of 100C, the LED current changes by less than 0.3mA. This is a couple times smaller change than with a LED with a resistor.
This "improvement" is not very useful in your application at 5V. But if you wanted to run from a 3.3V supply over a wide temperature range, then it would be necessary.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The two transistor junctions should be held at the same temperature. This needs to be addressed by the layout: both transistors should connect to a large ground plane, have a thick trace connecting the bases together, and then thin traces for other connections. This technique works for both through-hole and SMD transistors. For through-hole TO92 and TO226 parts, the flat faces of two packages should be glued together. For TO126, TO220 and similar parts, put a tiny dab of thermal grease on the heatsink, and screw the two heatsink faces together using.
This circuit is easy to turn on and off quickly. A digital 3.3V control signal can turn the LED on and off at a frequency higher than 10kHz. LOW control signal enables the LED, HIGH control signal turns the LED off.

simulate this circuit
